# Why does my module's hook block_list_alter only list a few blocks?

Tags: 7, blocks

```
function mymodule_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {
  foreach ($blocks as $block_id => $block) {
    debug($block->module);
  }
}
```

the above code debugs only two messages, each time "system". I've changed the weight of my module which still just debugs very few blocks. What am I missing?

The module itself provides a block which I simply want to hide from the block list/ overview. It has a webform dependency.

Thanks